# How do I fetch a response and then perform array shuffle on it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, response, shuffle

I have a block of code here. It fetches 4 API calls to pokiapi, converts the response to JSON, then converts that response to only show the name, and so when `Promise.all()` resolves it should return an array of 4 Pokemon name.

```
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const randNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)

    Promise.all([
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum1),
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum2),
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum3),
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum4),
    ])
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.name)))
    .then(responses => console.log(responses))
}
```

The last line of code is to console log the response and I get what I expected, which is an array of Pokemon name. An example might be ["mewtwo", "jynx", "ponyta", "geodude"].

BUT, when I include a new line just before console log to shuffle the previous array using `fisherYatesShuffle()`, the console log now returns undefined:

```
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const randNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)

    Promise.all([
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum1),
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum2),
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum3),
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum4),
    ])
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.name)))
    .then(responses => this.fisherYatesShuffle(responses))
    .then(responses => console.log(responses))
}
```

I don't think the `fisherYatesShuffle()` method is wrong because I've tried it on other arrays I make for testing purposes and it was perfectly fine. Just in case, here is the implementation of the fisherYatesShuffle().

```
//Takes in an array and returns a shuffled array
fisherYatesShuffle(guesses) {
    for (let i = guesses.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)
        const temp = guesses[i]
        guesses[i] = guesses[j]
        guesses[j] = temp
    }
}
```

I suspect that this is a problem with the way the responses are returned, but what can it be?

**Edit:** Ah apparently the problem WAS my `fisherYatesShuffle()` method. I originally tested it with some random arrays I made but my testing must've been bad because it didn't catch my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `fisherYatesShuffle` doesn't return anything. (There is no `return` statement in it.) Instead it simply re-orders the array that's passed to it. This means that `.then(responses => this.fisherYatesShuffle(responses))` puts `undefined` as the intermediate result of the Promise chain, so that's what you observe in the `console.log`.

There are 2 potential fixes, depending on which part you want to change.

Option 1 - make `fisherYatesShuffle` return its contents:

```
fisherYatesShuffle(guesses) {
    for (let i = guesses.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)
        const temp = guesses[i]
        guesses[i] = guesses[j]
        guesses[j] = temp
    }
    return guesses; // add this line
}
```

Option 2 - change the promise chain to explicitly return the shuffled array:

```
.then(responses => {
    this.fisherYatesShuffle(responses);
    return responses;
})
.then(responses => console.log(responses))
```